# Webview with app purchase to remove ads, what's the best option?

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an app that uses webview, and the only interaction with the android part is if the user click back in home, which asks if the user want to exit the app.
All other interactions are inside webview html5 content. The action bar is hidden too.

I have an ads block in MainActivity.java:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And after this it's the webview part.

And the activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

The webview and the ads are inside a RelativeLayout.

What's the best option to allow users to purchase the app to remove the ads block?

1. Publish 2 versions of the app, one free with the ads block, and in the html5 content a link to purchase the pro version without the ads (which opens in google play).
2. Somehow put a button to purchase the app in html5 content which triggers the part where the user buy the app, and after that perform a check to see if the user completed the purchase remove the ads.

I think the first option it's a good one, since I am a newbie with android studio I don't know how, or if it's possible to do the second (link the html5 content to buy the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this Premiumer library?
https://github.com/tslamic/premiumer

I think this is the exactly what you want. This is the second option for your question. It will be helpful.

Comment: Wow! Didn't knew this! With this I can add a button which will trigger the purchase? I mean, in the html5 content inside webview, and not a button directly in android code.

Comment: To place button inside html view and get a callback from webview, you need to add javascript interface to webview. See this guide.https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Thanks! It will help me a lot!